# HTML: Replace text smiles by images

Tags: javascript, html, regex, dom

Let's assume there are these two strings:

- `Test message :/`
- `This too <a
  href="http://example.com">Example.com</a> :/`

Now I replace the smile with this an image like that:

```
var message = 'Test message :/';
console.log(message.replace(/:\//ig, '<img src="smile1.png" alt=":/">'));

var message2 = 'This too: <a href="http://example.com">http://example.com</a> :/';
console.log(message2.replace(/:\//ig, '<img src="smile1.png" alt=":/">'));
```

How could I change the RegExp that it should just replace strings like `:/` outside of HTML tags?

Comment: queue comments about RegExp and HTML in 5, 4, 3,

Comment: Yes, I know this discussion, but could you tell me how to solve this issue then? The whole page/app is running just on client side.

Comment: what do you want to replace it with?

Comment: Everything is stored and processed client side. What exactly did you mean with your last question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this simple case a lookeahead assertion is fine:

```
message2 = 'smile :/  <a href="http://example.com">Example.com</a> :/ <img alt=":/"> and :/'
message2.replace(/:\/(?=[^<>]*(<|$))/g, "FOO")
> "smile FOO  <a href="http://example.com">Example.com</a> FOO <img alt=":/"> and FOO"
```

But in general, structured approach works much better with html. Walk the DOM tree, locate text nodes and do a simple string replacement there.

For those wondering, this regexp means

```
/
    :\/           a smile
    (?=           followed by
        [^<>]*    some chars but not < or >
        (         and then
            <|$   < or the end of input
        )
    )
/
```

To handle things like `http://`, add one more lookahead, this time negative: "not followed by a slash":

```
message2 = 'This too: <a href="http://example.com">http://example.com</a> :/';
message2.replace(/:\/(?=[^<>]*(<|$))(?!\/)/g, "FOO")
> "This too: <a href="http://example.com">http://example.com</a> FOO"
```

But to repeat myself: regexp is NOT your tool of choice when working with html.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! makes sense now, I thought `^` is used to say pattern starts with.. I don't get this part `[^<>]*`

Comment: @thg435 Thanks for this solution and additional the great visualization/description! I made a little mistake while typing the example. I didn't include the that inside the link smiles like `:/` could be also possible => Updated my post. Could you check my update?

Answer (score 1):

I've taken another approach, by using the DOM APIs instead of regexes: http://jsbin.com/EqUTUWE/6/edit

It turned out a bit verbose, so I will not paste it all here (you can check out the jsbin instead).

The basic approach is:

- Use a [`NodeIterator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeIterator) to iterate through each of the text nodes of the document
- For each text node, create a corresponding [`DocumentFragment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createDocumentFragment) that contains all its text, and the smiles substituted by image tags
- Replace the text nodes by the corresponding fragments.

I see a couple of benefits to this approach when compared to regexes:

- No issues with escaping. The browser will handle that for us for free.
- No need to manipulate HTML directly using `innerHTML` and such.
- Ease to extend the logic

It probably could use some performance improvement (and a lot of code cleanup), but should be enough to demonstrate the concept.